# Looking for better way to load initialization file(.bashrc) in jmeter

Tags: batch-file, jmeter

Currrently, I am running jmeter with this property to load my script for beanshell preprocessor.

```
 <apache jmeter Bin directory>/bin/jmeter -Jbeanshell.preprocessor.init=D:/commons.bshrc
```

I need shortcut to lauch JMeter with argument. I would like to store this property somewhere and would be able to use the short cut to load the same file when jmeter is started.

Example : when I click on "apache-jmeter.jar" file from bin directory, it opens jmeter GUI. But it should also load the commons.bshrc file.

Is there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create batch file:

```
@echo off
start /d "Java bin" -jar jmeter.jar -Jbeanshell.preprocessor.init=D:/commons.bshrc
```

Check out this wiki, about howto create batch file. http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Batch-File

Or you can easily edit your jmeter.bat file.